# How to fetch the content author name with views in twig?

Tags: views, 8

I am unable to fetch the content author name inside the twig template thorough views.

Below is what i did so far :
- Created a relationship under the advanced tab in views and added the Authored by field.

I can see the author in the preview section of the view but since i have overridden the template with views-view-filed i cant fetch it in twig with `{{ fields.author.user.name}}`

[image]

Kint is not of much help as its freezing the browser.

Comment: which type of twig template you are creating?

Comment: @Vikramfz16 I am not sure whether  i get your question Are you looking for : views-view-fields--VIEWNAME.html.twig

Comment: Print this twig variable  {{ fields.name.content }}  in your views-view-fields--VIEWNAME.html.twig

Comment: @Vikramfz16 the ouput for your above request is null. Is there a way to print all the fields ?

Comment: @Vikramfz16 yes you are right. But i was wrong in establishing the relationship. Now i get the value of the author correctly.

Comment: Could you make this a proper answer and accept it to help future readers to find the solution to that problem?

Comment: @Vikramfz16 can you also suggest variable name for getting the total comment statistics for the field : Content statistics: Total views i tried {{ fields.total_views.content_statistics}} doesn't seem to work though

Answer (score 0):

Better way to answer this is through  debugging the views fields by enabling the page_array check under the devel module settings.We get each and every fields that are available for the twig template.

There are two steps to get this working

Follow the steps mentioned in the comment:

1. https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-06-26/drupal-72-views-adding-authors-name-of-a-node#comment-4919120
2. You have to be careful while selecting the field .Please select the
   field marked in the attached image.
   [image]
3. Then in the twig template views-view-fields--VIEWNAME.html.twig the
   variable to be used is `{{fields.nane.content}}`

In addition to the above while researching for the variable name i found that most of the field names commonly used are available under `admin/reports/fields` in the backend of Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

You can custom views, as you can see in [views-view-unformatted.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view-unformatted.html.twig/8.2.x)

> Available variables:
>
> - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
> - rows: A list of the view's row items.
>
>   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
>   - content: The row's content.
> - view: The view object.
> - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be  used on rows.

If you want to use fields in a view template, use `views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine-name].html.twig`. There, you can print your fields like this:

```
<span>{{ fields.title.content }},</span><span>{{ fields.body.content }}</span><span>{{ fields.author.content }}</span>
```